# Event handler throws error in delegate type?

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling

I've event for Copy Proses, but I have a problem error in line cp.OnCopying :

> No overload for 'cp_copying' matches delegate
>   System.EventHandler 'System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs'

in line cp.OnCopyingComplete :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler'System.EventArgs''
>   to 'CustomProses.Completedelegate'

code:

```
public void SalinMultipleFile1()
{
   cp.OnCopying += new EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs>(cp_copying);
   cp.OnCopyingComplete += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(cp_CopySucces);
   cp.CustomCopy(DGVFile, tempFolder);
}

void cp_copying(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
{
   dfe.pbPerFile.Increment(e.PercentDelta);
}

void cp_CopySucces(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dfe.l_proses.Text = "Succes Copy";
}
```

class Custom Proses

```
Class CustomProses
{
   public delegate void ProgressChangeDelegate(double Persentage, ref bool Cancel);
   public delegate void Completedelegate();
   public event ProgressChangeDelegate OnCopying;
   public event Completedelegate OnCopyingComplete;
}
```

Does anyone know where the mistake lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your EventHandler assignments to something like this.

```
cp.OnCopying += cp_copying;
cp.OnCopyingComplete += cp_CopySucces;
```

Your eventhandlers also need to match the events exactly so change your eventhandlers to :

```
void cp_copying(double value, ref bool e)
{
    //dfe.pbPerFile.Increment(e.PercentDelta);
}

void cp_CopySucces()
{
   // dfe.l_proses.Text = "Succes Copy";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Completedelegate` takes no parameter and returns void.But you are trying to attach it your `cp_CopySucces` wich takes two parameter.

Your `ProgressChangeDelegate` takes one `double` and one `bool` parameter,but you are trying to attach it to `cp_copying` method which takes an `object` and `ProgressEventArgs` as parameter.

Your method and delegate signatures *should* match.Errors are obvious by the way.I think you need to read [Delegates Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)